# Connected-étale sequence $ 0 \to G^0 \to G \to G^{\text{ét}} \to 0$ for affine finite group scheme $G$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, group-schemes

Let $G$ be an affine finite commutative group scheme over a complete (or at least Henselian; thanks to [Jason Starr](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/424099/connected-etale-sequence-0-to-g0-to-g-to-g-mathrmet-for-affine-fini#comment1090163_424099) for calling attention to it) local ring $R$, and assume the residue field $\kappa=R/m$ of $R$ to be perfect. Denote by $K$ its quotient field. In Cornell's & Silverman's [Arithmetic Geometry](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4613-8655-1), p. 68, it is stated that the connected-étale sequence

$$ 0 \to G^0 \to G \to G^{\text{ét}}  \to 0$$

splits over the special fibre of $R$ because the residue field is perfect. Moreover, since $G$ is flat over $R$, this splitting (already true on the generic fibre) should hold over $R$ and therefore the connected-étale sequence is split exact.

Unfortunately I do not understand how one obtains the splitting of this sequence over $R$ knowing that it splits over special and generic fibers.

#Edit/update: if we reduce the business to associated Hopf algebras, we obtain the following diagram where horizontal sequences are exact:

$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
0 @>>> A^\text{ét} @>f>> A @>g>> A^o  @>>> 0\\
@VVV @VpVV @VVpV @VVpV  \\
0 @>>> A^\text{ét} \otimes_R \kappa @>\bar{f}>>  A \otimes_R \kappa @>\bar{g}>> A^{o} \otimes_R \kappa @>>> 0.
\end{CD}

The lower horizontal sequence splits and since $R$ is complete the idempotents of lower $R$-algebras lift to idempotents of upper ones. How can we ‘lift’ the splitting property to the upper sequence using this observation on idempotent lifting as Jason Starr suggested? Also, how would flatness be involved?

The splitting is equivalent to existence of section $s: A^o \to A$ with $gs=\operatorname{id}$. By flatness $A^o$ is a subalgebra of $A^{o} \otimes_R K$, so we can consider as promising candidate for $s$ the composition $A^o \hookrightarrow A^o \otimes_R K \to A \otimes_R K$ and we should hope that the image stays in $A$.

Also we know that there exists a section $\bar{s}:A^{o} \otimes_R \kappa \to A \otimes_R \kappa $. Note that up to now we nowhere used the idempotent lifting property. How could it help at this stage to make the final step to obtain the desired split? Here, that is equivalent to the fact that the constructed candidate for $s$ maps indeed to $A$.

But that's just my rough idea, probbly there is a better way to  argue here, I don't know.

Comment: Is the ring $R$ assumed to be Henselian (e.g., is it complete)?  If so, then you can lift idempotents.

Comment: @JasonStarr: Thank you, yes I overlooked that $R$ is assumed in the whole chapter to be 
complete. Assuming this now, how lifting idempotents would help here to 
obtain the desired splitting? Lifting idempotents says that 
there is a bijection between clopen subsets (=components) 
$Cl(G \otimes_R k) $ and $Cl(G)$ given by $A \mapsto p(A)$ for 
canonical map $G \otimes k \to G$. How can we conclude from this the 
exitence of the splitting? Moreover where in the argument the flatness
over $R$ is going to be exploited?

Comment: I don't think this is true. If $E$ is say an elliptic curve over $\mathbb Z_p$ with ordinary reduction and $G=E[p^n]$, then this extension splits only if $E$ is "close to" the canonical lift of its special fibre. In fact, usually the extension doesn't even split over the generic fibre $\mathbb Q_p$, as the corresponding Galois representation is not semisimple. In fact, if it splits over $\mathbb Q_p$, it does so over $\mathbb Z_p$ (using the valuative criterion of properness to extend the splitting).

Comment: Look, you are referencing a location in a book where the discussion is not about finite group schemes, but instead about p-divisible groups (as defined in the book you reference). The language Shatz uses is not my preferred one and for that reason, I wasn't able to see (in less than 5 mins) whether what he says on page 68 is correct or not. I have an interpretation that makes it look plausible however. Anyway, I hope readers who chance upon this page do not mistakenly assume that this book edited by Cornell and Silverman is a bad one -- it is a fantastic book IMHO. Cheers!